# Download pdf file using jspdf-autotable

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jspdf-autotable to download pdf file. My table id of html file is myTable. I am not getting pdf file as table.pdf.What shoule I change in my code? My code is below in javascript

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.2/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
    <script>
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
    doc.save("table.pdf"); </script>

</script>
```

Comment: The question is too generic to answer. Please also provide information about any errors received and the value of the variables res and elem.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'API' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:2267)
    at __webpack_require__ (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:39)
    at exports.__esModule (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:85)
    at jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:88
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:16)
    at jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:19

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put script tag within script tags. Change the code to:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.2/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
    doc.save("table.pdf");
</script>
```

Comment: Ya I am able to download the file ...How can I set the width of column of the table?

Comment: It should be documented in the repo. I think it is the columnWidth styles property though.